# marking up mutation positions in a sequence with html in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I was wondering if there are any methods in python or biopython that allows one to markup a sequence in html.

I would like to mark positions on a sequence (ie colour bases differently) according to if that position is a known snp/indel etc

Having a list of mutation positions in an array (read from a database) eg

mutation_position = [10,20,30,40]

I can change case for the affected base using something like:
seq = seq[0:b] + mutation_positions[b].lower() + seq[(b+1):len(seq)]

But is it possible to add some html code eg add the tag pos for each of the mutation positions. (when the html markup is added to the sequence, the length of the sequence is altered and so the mutation positions don't match to the newly marked up sequence during each iteration of the loop!)

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to make your mutations green and you had a list of mutations (0 indexed):

```
>>> seq = "ACGTACGT"
>>> muts = [0,1,5]
>>> mark_up = "<span style='color:green;'>%s</span>"

# use list comprehension to add mark up to muts
>>> marked_up_seq = [ mark_up % seq[x] if x in muts else seq[x] for x in range(0,len(seq)) ]

# rejoin marked up list
>>> "".join(marked_up_seq)
"<span style='color:green;'>A</span><span style='color:green;'>C</span>GTA<span style='color:green;'>C</span>GT"
>>>
```

With numbers for clarity:

```
>>> seq = "0123456789"
>>> muts = [1,3,4,9]
>>> marked_up_seq = [ mark_up % seq[x] if x in muts else seq[x] for x in range(0,len(seq)) ]
>>> "".join(marked_up_seq)
"0<span style='color:green;'>1</span>2<span style='color:green;'>3</span><span style='color:green;'>4</span>5678<span style='color:green;'>9</span>"
```

This isn't the most elegant solution, notice that the tags around 3 and 4 could be combined.

Answer (score 0):

Just using DTing's example (and HTML), maybe this is a little cleaner:

```
seq = "ACGTACGT"
muts = [0,1,5]
marked_up = ""

for pos, nuc in enumerate(seq):
    if pos in muts:
        marked_up = marked_up + "<span class=\"mutated\">" + nuc + "</span>"
    else:
        marked_up = marked_up + nuc

print marked_up
```

Then you just need to add a style to some CSS like:

```
span#mutated
{
    color:red;
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
<span class="mutated">A</span><span class="mutated">C</span>GTA<span class="mutated">C</span>GT
```

Which would look like this (if you swapped the span for `<b`> and `</b`>):

**A****C**GTA**C**GT